# PHP problems generating JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to generate json from a mysql statement using the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $arr_brand[] = array('ID' => $row['ID'],'Name' => $row['brand_name']);
        $arr_brands[] = array('Brand' => $arr_brand);

    }
```

however, This is how the JSON is coming out:

```
[{
  Brand: [{
      ID: "1",
      Name: "CocaCola"
  }]
}, {
  Brand: [{
      ID: "1",
      Name: "CocaCola"
  }, {
      ID: "2",
      Name: "Fanta"
  }]
}]
```

As you can see it is duplicating the first row in the database. Why is this and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Doing `$arr_brand[] = "something"` appends `"somrthing` to the array. You probably wanted reassignment `$arr_brand = "something"` .

Answer (score 2):

You will be duplicating a lot more than just the first row:

```
$arr_brand[] = array('ID' => $row['ID'],'Name' => $row['brand_name']);
$arr_brands[] = array('Brand' => $arr_brand);
```

In the first line you are adding a new element to the `$arr_brand` array so that array grows with every row. Then you add that growing array to your `$arr_brands` array.

So the first row of `$arr_brands` will contain the first row of your database result, the second one the first two rows, the third row the first three, etc.

You probably want:

```
$arr_brand = array('ID' => $row['ID'],'Name' => $row['brand_name']);
$arr_brands[] = array('Brand' => $arr_brand);
```